# Can I run a .NET application without installing the framework?

Tags: .net

The requirement is that we have to run our .NET code on the client machine where the client will not install the .NET framework on their machine. It should automatically run the .exe file, but without installing the framework the application will not run.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Some versions of Windows can run .NET programs without the user having to install the framework.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't run the executable on a machine without installing dotnet.

Check [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/157853/Running-the-c-exe-without-net-framework-on-machine).

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not allow to run the code without the framework. It cannot be executed.